# Different site themes and search engine bots

Tags: web, seo

I have a site which has support for custom themes (the same content, but different HTML, CSS, graphics), e.g. `default` theme, `mobile` theme etc.

Themes are switched via request params (`?theme=mobilie`) and saved in user session (database).

How should I serve those themes to search engine bots? Should I allow to crawl themes other than default as well? `robots noindex nofollow`, `canonical` tags in `head`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, themes and mobile versions are two different beasts, lets start with themes

lets say you have a ?theme=black and a ?theme=white theme and a default theme.

google does not care about your themes, as different themes just offer the same content in blue (or black, or whatever). this is a typical case of douplicate content.

so if you want to offer the users this option you should save it in the session.

```
www.example.com/?theme=black -> sets theme in session -> redirect HTTP 301 to -> www.example.com/
```

the "link" the users clicks should best be an external javascript (so that google can't easily discover that redirect link)

```
<span onclick="changeTheme('black')">Black</span>
```

so basically you offer google just the default version of your site, hide the themes (as they do not offer different content for google).

ok, about the mobile case.

if the HTML of the mobile site is optimized for mobile devices you might want to offer it to  googlebot mobile.

so you could do user agent detection (is this a mobile site) and redirect your mobile users to a mobile site i.e.: m.example.com (if it's a site optimized like this http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72462&from=40348&rd=1 and not only a smartphone optimized page) - then you should redirect googlebot mobile (not googlebot, just googlebot mobile) also to m.example.com (there is a whole chapter in googles seo guideline on how to do this http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf )